# Filter screenlog with screen command

Tags: grep, gnu-screen

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, lets me log output of the `screen` command. However, the output file is too large.
Is it possible to apply a `grep`-like filter so that I can control what gets logged?

For example, I might wish to log only lines which contain the phrase `foo bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I just skimmed through `man screen` so I am not absolutely sure whether it is possible to achieve without using external tools. However, one can use a named pipe and a combination of tail and grep to do this:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/fifo/fifo
$ tail -f /tmp/fifo/fifo | grep --line-buffered bar >> /tmp/DONE
```

Inside `screen` do:

```
logfile /tmp/fifo/fifo
```

and start logging. After finishing logging only lines that contained `bar` will be saved in `/tmp/DONE`. As it states in `man fifo`:

> A FIFO special file (a named pipe) is similar to a pipe, except that
>   it is accessed as part of the file system. It can be opened by
>   multiple processes for reading or writ- ing. When processes are
>   exchanging data via the FIFO, the kernel passes all data internally
>   without writing it to the file system. Thus, the FIFO special file has
>   no con- tents on the file system; the file system entry merely serves
>   as a reference point so that processes can access the pipe using a
>   name in the file system.

That means that `/tmp/fifo/fifo` takes no space on disk. This solution worked for me but I don't know what negative side-effects or shortcomings it may have.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that they recommend using `fifo` in `man script`:

> -f, --flush Flush output after each write. This is nice for telecooperation: one person does 'mkfifo foo; script -f foo', and
>   another can supervise real-time what is being done using 'cat foo'.

In case you didn't know, [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) is an utility that also records terminal session.